# Embedding Youtube video in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I am working on a web application in which I have to embed a youtube video related to a specific key word in an iframe. I am using the following HTML code for it:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=search&list=essay"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

When I run the code video is not loaded in the ifame. Can anyone let me know whats wrong with this code?

Comment: it looks like the url you used for embedding is invalid https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=search&list=essay

Comment: @Nair thanks for replying, but can you suggest me a valid url for the iframe source

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nWqMQ26Gqi4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

this is your video and this will work fine. your code is ok. but browser is the problem. most probably in firefox your video will work. but my code will work anyware.

If you want to add dynamic address to play use this

```
<iframe width="320" height="240" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'. $vedio_id.'?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

where $vedio_id is your dynamic word.

Comment: thanks for your answer but my requirement is that I need to load the youtube video in the ifram related to a particular word. Please note that this word may change dynamically based upon user selection. So I have to set the search word in the url. Getting the video by its Id won't work for me.

Comment: @Corporal see the new answer. that might help.

Comment: I tried with this url "http://www.youtube.com/embed/cricket?autoplay=1" but it still doesn't work. Is there any work around possible? or is there some way that i can get the video id of videos that are related to my key word. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  <iframe width="640" height="360"      
     src="//www.youtube.com/embed/sLAEg5aTXAE?feature=player_detailpage"
     frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
 </iframe>
```

Comment: in the url where can I give the keyword for the related video. I don't want to get video by video id.

Comment: how would you want to get the video aside from using its id ?

Comment: The thing is that I want that on my html page that whenever I double click a work, the youtube videos related to that particular word should populate in the iframe. So I need to set that word in the iframe url.